# jQuery and Bootstrap at least one of the fields to be filled

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, formvalidation.io

I am using formvalidation.io plugin to validate a Bootstrap form. It works fine with single form field, but when it comes a combination of fields to be checked, I have no idea how should I do it. Here is a sample code:

```
            facebook: {
                validators: {
                    uri: {
                        message: 'Please enter your Facebook address properly.'
                    }
                }
            },
            twitter: {
                validators: {
                    uri: {
                        message: 'Please enter your Twitter address properly.'
                    }
                }
            },
            instagram: {
                validators: {
                    uri: {
                        message: 'Please enter your Instagram address properly.'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now I want to force visitors to provide at least one of their Facebook, Twitter, or Instagram pages. How can I modify my code to do that?

Comment: More code please.  And have you tried anything specifically?

Comment: Full code can be found here: http://vahid.roushenas.com/profile